# "BOT" Server Issue, Isn't doing its job

Tags: javascript, java, putty, steam, steambot

I've recently made a website with a BOT which does sometimes automatically so I don't have to do it manually all the time. However, when someones tries to deposit something into the website, this is showing in Putty (where is start the server and bot): http://prntscr.com/cy0biv . I'm not experienced into coding and I need help. Where should I look and what could I have done wrong? Everything works perfectly, except this, and this is a major issue. Please do a favour and help me.
Thanks in advance,
Critical

Comment: Fire it and hire another bot instead.

Comment: So it seems you're trying to build a CS:GO trade bot. That's _probably_a against Steam TOS so...don't.

Comment: i'd like to get help and yes I know about that. But other "well-known" sites have these kinds of bots so I Don't think the bot itself is against Steam TOS.

Answer (score 0):

Is the bot account older than 7 days? the account needs to be 7 days old before you can send/recieve trades.

Comment: I signed into the the bot account yesterday and aktivares steam mobile authenticator. Might be that but I Don't know. I Don't want to waste 7 in case that isn't the problem.